# Some weird issue with template loading

Tags: angularjs, node.js, templates, express, pushstate

I'm trying to implement HTML5 push state in my angular app but to no avail.

Things seem to work fine (I can access every static file from the browser by typing the exact path (an example would be `http://localhost/components/profile/profile.html`) but when I try to load template through `templateUrl` option in state definiton it's not loading anything. No errors in the console neither. Are my routes set up correctly?

Worth mentioning: when switching to `profile` state I see `profile.js` request in the server, but no request for the template.

**Express routes:**

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/[^\.]+$', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile("index.html", { root: __dirname + '/public' });
});
```

**App config:**

```
function lazyLoad(pathjs) {
            return ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(pathjs);
            }];
        }

$stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            template: 'Welcome home'
        })
        .state('profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl: 'components/profile/profile.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                module: lazyLoad('components/profile/profile.js'),
                user: ['SessionService', function (SessionService) {
                    return SessionService.currentUser();
                }]
            }
        });

$locationProvider
        .html5Mode(true)
        .hashPrefix('!');
```

**Project tree:**

[image: Project tree]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was unresolved promise in the `resolve` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Does the issue remain if you set html5mode to false?

Comment: The issue remains with html5mode set to false.

Comment: @itdoesntwork, this should have been a comment to the question, instead of answer.

Comment: i know, but I need more reputation to comment :(